# Link to the same page but without ?arg=value parameters

Tags: 7, uri

How to create link in Drupal 7 that will redirect me to the same page but with omitting "?arg=value" query fragment?

The following code doesn't work, as it always add `?arg=value`.

```
<p><?php echo l(t('My Label'), 'views-page-url'); ?></p>
```

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>"><?php echo t('My Label'); ?></a></p>
```

Comment: What is the URL of the page? What do you get as from `l(t(My label'), 'views-page-url')`?

Comment: I get url <a href="views-page-url">My Label</a> without "?arg=value" which is what I exactly want, but when I click it goes to views-page-url?arg=value.